# Is there a maximum limit to the size of the query string for the pandas.read_sql() function?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, error-handling, read-sql

I have a Python script that takes a list of names from the user, creates an SQL query string, and queries the database and puts the data into a dataframe using `pandas.read_sql()` method. However, I have noticed that if the list of people I want to query is very very long, my code never reaches the line coming after `pandas.read_sql()`, and for some reason, no exception is caught.

My query string looks like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 
table1.name = 'Alice' OR
table1.name = 'Bob' OR
table1.name = 'Charlie' OR ...
```

where there could be hundreds of names included.

The Python code I am using looks like the following:

```
query_string = construct_string_above(names_list)
pymongoConnection = ... 

try:
    print("Trying")
    df = pandas.read_sql(query_string, pymongoConnection)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(0)

print("Finishing")
```

My code always executes up until the try block. The program prints "Trying" but never prints "Finishing" nor does it return any errors. I checked, and the `pymongoConnection` object is correct. I also tried executing the `query_string` manually in MySQL and it works.

The issue must be at `pandas.read_sql()` and even here, the issue only arises when the size of the query string exceeds a certain threshold, otherwise the code finishes correctly. Are there any limitations to the use of `pandas.read_sql()`, such as maximum size of input string or maximum `WHERE` clauses or maximum amount of data returned to the dataframe? Because I cannot think of anything else that might cause the problem.

Comment: What is the exact threshold? Can you determine it? It might be helpful.

Comment: It is very inconsistent. The only way I managed to get it was by trial and error. It is around 120 names but it varies across different servers (I develop this code to run on a remote server), so I am really coding blindly in the dark